# OAuth 2.0 Services variations

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement an authentcation module which I can reuse for different services. I have gone through some popular OAuth 2.0 implemented services. I did find some differences in some of the authentication calls, Like, Microsoft Dyanmics adds an extra query parameter, resource=ABC, to the authorization code call. 2nd example, Twitter sends a 4 5 paramters while invoking their oauth service. 
**My ques:** Are all this services oauth 2.0 compliant? As in case of dynamics, RFC never mentions resource parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right there is no mention of a `resource` parameter in the RFCs related to the OAuth2 FrameWork Protocol or the OpenID Connect Specification.

In fact, that parameter is part of an IETF draft: [Resource Indicators for OAuth 2.0](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-campbell-oauth-resource-indicators).

There are other on-going specifications managed by the [OAuth2 Working Group](https://tools.ietf.org/wg/oauth/). Have a look at those documents, it may help you to understand why and how Microsoft, Twitter and other service providers use  specific parameters.

Comment: Thanks. The working group is a big help.
Lots of drafts to go through.